# How should I implement canonical urls in my prestashop theme?

Tags: seo, prestashop, canonical-link

canonical urls are currently activated on the shop, but the won't be written in frontend source code. So I took a look even to the default-bootsrap theme, the last from github, but it seems it doesn't implement any canonical url.

I also checked all the controllers, but it seems no one sets a $canonical_url (something like..) smarty var, so what the hell is the related backoffice option?

I searched the web but found nothing really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backoffice option Canonical url is only used in controllers.

If you have activated the url rewriting option and try to access this link:

```
http://dev.test.com/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product
```

You will be redirected to, for example:

```
http://dev.test.com/tshirts/1-T-shirts-a-manches-courtes-delaves.html
```

Here is an extract from the `canonicalRedirection` method from `FrontController` class:

```php
/**
 * Redirects to canonical URL
 *
 * @param string $canonical_url
 */
protected function canonicalRedirection($canonical_url = '')
{
    [...]

    $redirect_type = Configuration::get('PS_CANONICAL_REDIRECT') == 2 ? '301' : '302';
    header('HTTP/1.0 '.$redirect_type.' Moved');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    Tools::redirectLink($final_url);
}
```

In this method we get the canonical redirect option you selected in the BackOffice with this line `Configuration::get('PS_CANONICAL_REDIRECT')`.

If you want canonical url in your html header you'll have to write or get a module for that as it is not included in Prestashop.